# Type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage when using Dictionary with IEnumerable values

Tags: c#, generics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{

    static List<T> F<T>(IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<T>> dictionary)
    {
        // ...
        return new List<T>();
        // ...
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var mydict = new Dictionary<int, LinkedList<int>>();
        F(mydict);
    }
}
```

The error message after [running the code](http://ideone.com/y1Pbs0):

```
prog.cs(16,3): error CS0411: The type arguments for method `Test.F<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: This code is incorrect simply because you're declaring it as taking `IEnumerable<T>` but you're giving it a `LinkedList<T>`, if the code compiled you would be able to stuff a `List<T>` into the dictionary passed to the method. If you change your `mydict` declaration to also use `IEnumerable<T>`, the code compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary<int, LinkedList<int>>` is not a `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>`.

You will need to use a signature like:

```
static List<T> F<T, U>(IDictionary<int, U> dictionary) where U : IEnumerable<T>
```

So that you can pass an argument that is a dictionary where the key type is `int` and the value type is a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` but is not (necessarily) `IEnumerable<T>` itself.

Unfortunately the type still won't be inferable, so it will have to be called with:

```
F<int, LinkedList<int>>(mydict);
```

Answer (score 5):

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is invariant in the value type, so an `IDictionary<int, LinkedList<int>>` is not an `IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>` even though `LinkedList<int>` is an `IEnumerable<int>`.